# Is there anyway put a UILabel to a CPTSymbol?

Tags: objective-c, core-plot

I need to show some text at the CPTSysmol position,is there anyway can solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to label data points with their values, use "data labels". Otherwise, attach a plot space annotation to the data point and use a `CPTTextLayer` in the annotation to display the text.